# How to update child state first and than parent's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

> **In short :-**

I want to update child state first and than update parent state but react batches setSate and calls parent setState first and than childs. For more understanding read the explanation written below.

> Basically i have a parent component which is having two child.

1. **Sort component :-**  This component opens a dropdown for sort options selection. on click it should update the local state and than call the function passed as props from parent.
2. **Product collection :-**  This component shows the products based on the sort selected.

I am passing a function (**`handleClick`**) from parent component to sort to get the value of selected sort into the parent and than passing it to product collection.

Since sort is a dropdown i want to close it first as soon as user selects a option and than i want to update the parent.

Right now i am using it in such a way, first updating local state and in callback calling the function passed from parent.

```
handleClick(param) {
    this.setState({ selectedType: param.slug }, () =>
      this.props.onHandleSort(param.slug)
    )
  }
```

But as written in [**React docs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous) it batches the process and calls the parent setState first and than the child.

> For example, that if both Parent and Child call setState
>   during a click event, Child isn’t re-rendered twice. Instead, React
>   “flushes” the state updates at the end of the browser event. This
>   results in significant performance improvements in larger apps.

I need it to happen in such way only because i need my dropdown to close first and than the parent should update.

> I have tried the following this but nothing seems to work.

1. Made sort component stateless and dependent on the props from the parent but this will take time to close the dropdown.
2. Used callback of setState but since as written in docs it batches and calls parent setState first and than childs.

Comment: Does setting `selectedType` cause the dropdown to close

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes it closes the dropdown.

Comment: Can you show that part of the code

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am using reakit for a dropdown and you can see here code for sort component https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeRqyz?editors=0010

Comment: I think you should just keep the `selectedType` in the parent. React emphasizes a top-down data flow model, and the problems you're experiencing are due to trying to go against it.

Comment: @KenoClayton yeah i tried that part too, but here my requirement is such that i need to keep a local state to close the dropdown as soon as user clicks on it.

Comment: Also if you're doing this just to close the dropdown, why not just use some style based workaround to hide the element (animate it if you want), and `onAnimationEnd` maybe hide the component or change the state.

Comment: As an example, you could use the `handleClick` to set a flag to hide the element. In the element, you add that class if your flag is true, and you also add your animation/transition listener which will trigger the state in the parent. You could also look into using a library built for those types of transitions like React Spring https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition

Comment: @KenoClayton here in sort i have a field where i have to show the selected filter. it's not just about closing the dropwdown mate. sorry if i wasn't clear enough in my question

Answer (score 2):

Judging from [your codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeRqyz?editors=0010), you should lift the `withRouter`-wrapper up to the parent, let it figure out the `selectedType` and pass it to your sort component. In your `onHandleSort`, you can then set the new `query`.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  // ...
  handleClick (slug) => {
    this.props.router.push({ query: { sorting: slug } })
  }
  // ...
  render () {
    const sorting = this.props.router && this.props.router.query
      ? this.props.router.query.sorting
      : 'RELEVANCE';

    return (
      // ...
      <Sort value={sorting} onHandleSort={this.handleClick} />
      // ...
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Parent);
```

```
export default class Sort extends Component {
  // ...
  handleClick (param) => {
    this.props.onHandleSort(param.slug)
  }
  // ...
  render () {
    const selectedType = this.props.sorting;

    return (
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. i already tried this, but in my case i need a local state as i want to close dropdown as soon as user clicks. so if i do via props it will not close dropdown as soon as user clicks.